# EF: При добавлении или удалении сущности записи в GridControl не изменяются

Tags: c#, entity-framework, devexpress

Я пытаюсь использовать сущности EF, компонент entityServerModeSource из DevExpress. Код в OnLoad такой:

```
        tblRegion = dte.T_Regions;
        entityServerModeSourceRegions.QueryableSource = tblRegion;
        entityServerModeSourceRegions.KeyExpression = "id";
```

Затем пытаюсь по кнопке добавить сущность:

```
    T_Regions region = new T_Regions();
    region.id = id;
    region.Title = tbRegion.Text;
    tblRegion.Add(region);
    gridRegion.RefreshDataSource(); // Не помогает
    //gridRegion.DataSource = entityServerModeSourceRegions; // Не помогает
    //gvRegion.RefreshData(); // Не помогает
    //gridRegion.Refresh(); // Не помогает
```

Новые записи в GridControl не появляются. Так же не обновляется при удалении.
Сохранять в базу нужно после всех изменений по другой кнопке:

```
    private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            dte.SaveChanges();
            gridRegion.RefreshDataSource();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Utils.ExceptionMessage(ex, "Ошибка сохранения изменений в БД!");
        }
    }
```

Скажите, как надо правильно делать?

Comment: Нашел такое решение:  

    tblRegion.Add(region);
    gridRegion.DataSource = tblRegion.Local;  
Из справки:
Возвращает объект ObservableCollection<T>, содержащий локальное представление всех добавленных, неизменившихся и измененных сущностей в наборе.Это локальное представление остается синхронизированным по мере добавления или удаления сущностей из контекста. Аналогичным образом добавляемые или удаляемые из этого локального представления сущности автоматически добавляются в контекст или удаляются из контекста.

Comment: Ответ пишите как ответ, он для того и ответ, а не комментарий

Comment: Ясно. Учту. К стати, форматировать что-то не удалось.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел такое решение:

```
        tblRegion.Add(region);
        gridRegion.DataSource = tblRegion.Local;
```

Из справки:

> Возвращает объект ObservableCollection, содержащий локальное представление всех добавленных, неизменившихся и измененных сущностей в наборе.Это локальное представление остается синхронизированным по мере добавления или удаления сущностей из контекста. Аналогичным образом добавляемые или удаляемые из этого локального представления сущности автоматически добавляются в контекст или удаляются из контекста.

Comment: Добрый день Vasly Bondarev.
В моём проекте понадобилось использовать EntityServerModeSource, так как загружается много данных, но при попытке создать экземпляр этого класса выдаёт ошибку

The type or namespace name 'EntityServerModeSource' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

хотя по мануалу DevExpress я использую правильный Namespace. Скажите пожалуйста в чём может быть проблема ? использую entityframework 6, devexpress V 12, .net 4

Comment: Здравствуйте! Убедитесь что кроме Namespace:DevExpress.Data.Linq у Вас добавлена сборка DevExpress.Data.v12.2.dll